# Consuming REST Service with WCF - Basic Authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-3.0

I'm trying to consume a REST service with Basic Authentication with an odd problem. The first request made does not include the basic authentication credentials specified. This happens for every first request made. It happens every time the application starts. It does not happen for subsequent requests. I am using the `ClientBase<T>` class to call the API, which looks something like this:

```
public class MyApi : ClientBase<IMyApi>
{
    protected override IMyApi CreateChannel()
    {
        //Remove all client credentials. 
        ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.RemoveAll<ClientCredentials>();

        //Create new client credentials and add to the endpoint behaviours.
        ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
        clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Username;
        clientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;
        ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(clientCredentials);

        return base.CreateChannel();
    }

    public MyApi() : base (DefaultEndpointName)
    {}
}
```

My binding is setup as follows:

```
  <customBinding>        
    <binding name="myApiBinding">
      <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="ContentTypeMapper,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" authenticationScheme="Basic" realm="myRealm" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

I have tried bumping the project up to .Net 4, adding the client credentials after initialising the API, but none seem to have the desired the effect.

Is there a way to get the credentials added for every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462256/double-request-while-making-pox-rest-call-using-wcf-with-webhttpbinding-set-to-b).

The first answer explains why... (The server should be responding to the first request with an authentication challenge)

The second answer explains how to work around... (By manipulating request http header to manually insert the basic authentication credentials)

Comment: Looking at the answer, it seems verbose as it has to be added to every method in the API? It looks like `OperationContextScope` is the culprit. Is there a way to add this to the `CreateChannel` method or a constructor? I tried but saw some very strange results.

Comment: You might be able to create the OperationContextScope in the CreateChannel() method after the base.CreateChannel() call.  Just remember to override Dispose() and also dispose your OperationContextScope.

Comment: I gave that a try to no avail. Cassini even crashed at one point. It seems the only way is to make a generic method that uses and disposes of the OperationContextScope, adds the required headers and calls your required method via a Func<T> or something similar.